# Different Notifications for Smart watch and Phone

Tags: android, notifications, sony-smartwatch

Im looking for a way to send 2 different notifications out from an app. On the phone the notification will display one notification but on the watch it needs 2 display 3 separate notifications. Is there a way to send these to the watch so that they don't display on the phone as well?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to send separate notifications to the watch. Google walks through the process of how to add wearble features to notifications here:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/index.html

This page shows you how to send a wearable only notification:

http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating.html

In particular this section from the above site:

> **Specify Wearable-only Actions**
>
> If you want the actions available on the wearable to be different from
>   those on the handheld, then use WearableExtender.addAction(). Once you
>   add an action with this method, the wearable does not display any
>   other actions added with NotificationCompat.Builder.addAction(). That
>   is, only the actions added with WearableExtender.addAction() appear on
>   the wearable and they do not appear on the handheld.
>
> // Create an intent for the reply action
>
> ```
> Intent actionIntent = new Intent(this, ActionActivity.class);
>
> PendingIntent actionPendingIntent =
>         PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, actionIntent,
>                 PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
>
> // Create the action
> NotificationCompat.Action action =
>         new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.drawable.ic_action,
>                 getString(R.string.label), actionPendingIntent)
>                 .build();
>
> // Build the notification and add the action via WearableExtender
> Notification notification =
>         new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
>                 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_message)
>                 .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.title))
>                 .setContentText(getString(R.string.content))
>                 .extend(new WearableExtender().addAction(action))
>                 .build();
> ```